# Solving differential equation from Cauchy problem $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2 -2e^{2t} + e^{4t} + 2e^{2t}, (t,x) ∈ R^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've found the following exercise in one of my courses. How can I solve the 
following Cauchy equation?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2 -2e^{2t}x + e^{4t} + 2e^{2t}, (t,x) ∈ R^2$$
$$x(0)=2$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems having missed something on the RHS.

Comment: @user115350 thanks, missed an x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to solve this kind of problem, but if you look at the first $3$ terms on the right, they are $(x-e^{2t})^2$. This suggests the substitution $u=x-e^{2t}$ so that $x=u+e^{2t}$ and
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}+2e^{2t}=u^2+2e^2t$$
Now it's easy.
$$\frac{du}{u^2}=dt$$
$$-\frac1u=\frac{-1}{x-e^{2t}}=t+C$$
$$x=e^{2t}-\frac1{t+C}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2 -2e^{2t}x + e^{4t} + 2e^{2t}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \left( x - e^{2t}\right)^2 + 2e^{2t}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} - 2e^{2t}= \left( x - e^{2t}\right)^2$$

Let, 
$$u = x - e^{2t}$$

and, $\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} - 2 e^{2t}$. Therefore,

$$\frac{du}{dt} = u^2$$
$$u(t = 0) = 1$$

Solving this

$$t - C= - \frac{1}{u}$$
$$u = \frac{1}{C - t}$$
Applying the initial condition
$C = 1$
Therefore.
$$x - e^{2t} = \frac{1}{1 - t}$$

$$x = \frac{1}{1 - t}+ e^{2t}$$